# Automatic continuation of enumeration

Tags: enumerate

I'm interesting in automatically continuing the enumeration in my document. Take a look at the following MWE.

```
    %compile with XeLaTeX
    \documentclass[12pt]{memoir}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    
    \begin{document}
        
    \begin{flushleft}
        
        \lipsum[1]
        
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
            \item This is the first item
            
            \item This is the second item
            
            \item ....
        \end{enumerate}
        
        \lipsum[2]
        
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=4]
            \item This is the fourth item
            
            \item This is the fifth item
        \end{enumerate}
        
        \lipsum[3]
        
    \end{flushleft}
 \end{document}
```

Is it possible when I start the second enumeration to somehow tell LaTeX to **start exactly where the previous enumeration ended instead of typing start=4 for example?**

Comment: Have you tried `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.},resume]`? You can define your own environment `\newenvironment{resumenum}{\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.},resume]}{\end{enumerate}}` if you want to avoid having to type all that over and over again. I.e.:  `\begin{resumenum}\item ... \item...\end{resumenum}`

Comment: Since you're loading the `enumitem` package, you may achieve your formatting objective by replacing `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, start=4]` with `\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}, resume]`.

Comment: Another solution could be linguex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is why the `enumitem` package offers the `resume` option. The option `resume*` keeps also the label definition (thanks to @daleif for the amendment).

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\arabic*.}]
\item This is the first item
\item This is the second item
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item This is the fourth item
\item This is the fifth item
\end{enumerate}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: if you use `resume*` then you don't need to repeat the label definition.

Comment: Thanks for the amendment, I've modified the post. I should have continued reading the docs after finding `resume` ...

Comment: `resume` and `resume*` are a bit strange. `resume*` can only be used if you explicitly used `label` etc in the `[]` argument. If instead you inject `\setlist` into `\begin{enumerate}` then `resume*` does not work, but `resume` does. Probably too late to clean up now.

Comment: @daleif Feel free to edit my post however you like, or post a second answer. It may not be relevant for the OP, but Google will direct more people to this page in the future.